# How can I draw ip addresses to geo location map

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a web application that collect user ip addresses when user login, I want to drwa all collected ip addresses to a map that will show me a pin on the country have one or more user loged in from it
example: let us say we have the following ip addresses in a database
xx.ee.rr.tt = USA
cc.ee.ww.aa = UK

I need a world map with pins on USA and UK

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far, and where you got stuck.  If you haven't tried anything yet, please give it a go, and then come back to the site if you have specific problems.  See the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, especially the section "search, and research".  Showing your research will help you get better, more relevant answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few good examples of mapping IP to country (or Country IP Blocks).

Here is a [free restful API service](http://freegeoip.net/) you can call to do this - you're limited to 10k queries per hour.

They are on [GitHub](https://github.com/fiorix/freegeoip) in case you want to copy and run the code locally and to get around this 10k constraint or speed things up.

Here is a sample output of a query on my IP address (I'll mask it, but you'll get the idea)

```
IP  198.70.xxx.xxx
Country United States
Region  Ohio
City    Xxxxx
Latitude and Longitude  4x.xxx -8x.xxx
Area and Metro codes    330 -
```

Here is a [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90598/Using-IP-to-Country-Web-Service-Within-NET-Applica) article on consuming the WSIP2Country service.  (If you go this route, note that the GetCountryCode method was deprecated and recommend using the GetCountryCodeAuth - see comments at the end of the article).

---

This works if you are only trying to derive location from the IP address - per your comment you want to also go the next step and pin it to a map.  There are some great ways to incorporate Google Maps for this.

[This site's](http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/ipmapper/) IP Mapper method/code has been used quite successfully by many (it boasts: "Asynchronously Geocode IP Addresses on Google Maps").  They have a way to add a list of IP addresses in their example code:

```
var ipArray = ["111.111.111.111", "222.222.222.222", "123.123.123.123"];
IPMapper.addIPArray(ipArray);
```

They utilize the Google map API, so you should be able to modify their JavaScript code using the [Google Map API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls?hl=en) as a guide if you want anything special.

Comment: I want some thing like ip (many ip addresses) to map builder I don't care if it's free or not

Comment: Ok - so you have the IP and country code, but want to then draw it to a map?  I thought you still needed to derive the country code from the IP.

Comment: @SaleemAhmad Modified the answer to include mapper.